# Installation error in sphinx4

Tags: cmusphinx

BUILD FAILED
/home/anu/speech/sphinx4/sphinx4/build.xml:227: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/anu/speech/sphinx4/sphinx4/build.xml:248: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre"

Answer (score 0):

JRE and JDK are two different things. JRE is runtime environment to execute java programs. JDK is development environment to compile java programs. Error message says you don't have JDK under JAVA_HOME. You need to unstall JDK and configure JAVA_HOME environment variable to point on it.